# use cin to name a tarball from with C++

Tags: c++, zip, gzip, tar

Here is my current code which I am stumped on. Yes I an sort of new to C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using std::string;
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    string projectname;

    std::cout << "Enter your project folders name: ";
    std::cin >> projectname;

    // Idea is to call tar, gzip and zip

    // Create the tarball from using cin for file title
    system("tar -cvf projectname.tar");  projectname;

    // using cin gzip the tarball
    system("gzip projectname.tar");

    // then call md5sum and sha1sum to get the hash for each
    system("md5sum projectname.tar.gz > gz.log");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is not working, I need it to get the file variable from cin

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `stringstream` to "print" the complete string, or you can use `+` to concatenate the parts. And if you use `cvfz` in your tar-command, you get a `.gz` file directly from `tar`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the separate parts of the command inserting your variable *projectname* in the relevant place like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using std::string;
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    string projectname;

    std::cout << "Enter your project folders name: ";
    std::cin >> projectname;

    // Idea is to call tar, gzip and zip

    // add the different parts into a string
    // then convert to a char const* using c_str()
    system(("tar -cvf '" + projectname + ".tar' '" + projectname + "'").c_str());

    // Same thing broken down

    string command = "gzip '";
    command += projectname;
    command += ".tar'";

    system(command.c_str());

    // etc....
}
```

Comment: Tar still doesn't find the name from cin, folder exist

Comment: @Keldo I don't know how `tar` works, I'm just here for the `C++`. But I think you maybe need to tell tar what files to add to the archive. Figure out the correct `tar` command from the command-line and then create it according to how I explained and it should all work.

Comment: tar -czvf projectname.tar.gz projectname where projectname comes from cin but its still not reading the input. Tar fails cause it will not create an empty directory, due to no input reaching the projectname variable

Comment: @Keldo I modified the answer to something I think should work according to my reading of the `tar` and `gzip` instructions.

Comment: What does "doesn't find the folder" mean? Is your program executing in the right directory? [And why are you doing this in C++ in the first place, surely there is some suitable scripting language that can do this without needing to compile and stuff]

Comment: @Keldo You have to give tar the folder name and *also* a name to call the archive. Your example implies the same name is used for both.Otherwise you need to ask for an archive name (for the tar file) and a folder name (where the project is).

Comment: @Mats a folder called test exist with a simple one line text file inside it, at cin I type test, it should create test.tar.gz and eventually md5sum and sha1sum of that file. It in itself when using czvf is not finding the folder when the name is typed into cin. and if I choose to use C++ as a means to learn how to do this, then its C++ I will use.